# Deserialize Google Web Kit Response (Java) and Java Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, serialization, gwt

I have a monolithic legacy application that I need to read and submit data to. It's using Google Web Kit and Java Servlets. 
I have access to the source code, but I'm new to both Servlets and GWT.

I'm trying to encapsulate a rest client in my project that can communicate with GET/POST rest calls to the legacy server.

I've been able to send a POST request using Postman, and then used Reactive Spring 5.0 framework to sending that request.

When I try to deserialize the response, I'm running into a ton of errors.

**How would I deserialize this payload?**

```
7|0|7|http://localhost:8080/testproject/
|29F4EA1240F157649C12466F01F46F60|
com.test.client.GreetingService|greetServer|java.lang.String|
myInput1|myInput2|1|2|3|4|2|5|5|6|7|
```

I've searched all day, and followed a few blogs like these: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eG0YocsYYbNAtivkLtcaiEE5IOF5u4LUol8-LL0TIKU/edit#
https://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/2009/10/8/gwt-rpc-in-a-nutshell.html

I'm not sure code wise how I can serialize them into my own object for my new service.

```
static WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Mono<String> body = Mono.just("7|0|7|http://localhost:8080/testproject/|29F4EA1240F157649C12466F01F46F60|com.test.client.GreetingService|greetServer|java.lang.String|myInput1|myInput2|1|2|3|4|2|5|5|6|7|");

    Mono<String> response = webClient.post()
            .uri("http://localhost:8080/testproject/")
            .header("Content-Type", "text/x-gwt-rpc;charset=UTF-8")
            .header("X-GWT-Module-Base", "http://localhost:8080/testproject/")
            .header("X-GWT-Permutation", "29F4EA1240F157649C12466F01F46F60")
            .cookie("JSESSIONID", "2BCEBF12GE2C3A0335F5012812A73638")
            .body(body, String.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);

    String unBlocked = response.block();

    System.out.println(unBlocked);
    //OK[1,1,["java.lang.Integer/3438228391"],0,2]

    try {
    ServerSerializationStreamReader streamReader = new ServerSerializationStreamReader(
        Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), null);
        streamReader.prepareToRead(unBlocked);
        System.out.println(streamReader.readObject());
    } catch ( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error:
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on your browser. ( Malformed or old RPC message received - expecting version between 5 and 7 )

I've tried every version of GWT because of the malformed RCP message. 
Also, I tried to stick it into a string, which I'm sure is failing on its own.

Comment: Is the 'payload' just a `String`? If it is, and if the values are always in that order, you can just use the `split` method on the pipe. Then you'll have a `String[]` of the values that you can loop through and do whatever you want with.

Comment: It has pretty complex objects. I could pull out the models and use them in my project.  

For simplicity, is it possible to make a toString on this, and print all values as if it was a JsonObject, or something similar ? 

Once I can wrap my head around that, I could start pulling in pieces.

Comment: I mean, anything is possible. However, I don't understand how you're obtaining the 'payload'. Could you maybe update your post to include the code that obtains the 'payload'? If it really is just a `String`, you can easily turn it into JSON.

Comment: Can you share the errors you are getting and the code you've written so far? What you are trying is very doable, but it does take some setup, you can see that GWT does it in the RemoteServiceServlet as an example.

Comment: @FrancisBartkowiak & Colin

I've updated the the post with the additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to decode the *server response* with the code meant decode the *client request*. At present they use a different format for historical reasons - note how the response starts with "//OK", but the request has the version/flags/stringcount "7|0|7" beginning.

In at least a small part this is because when a client calls a server, it needs to describe what version it is speaking and where the server should find the file listing the set of classes that the client expects are allowed to be serialized. When the server responds, since the client already told it about the typed that can be serialized, it doesn't need to tell the client the same thing again.

Reading the `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader` class and its docs will show the response format and how it can be decoded into objects. There is presently no server-side code that I'm aware of that is intended to do this job, but could probably be written with fairly little difficulty, just some persistence.

Comment: Thank you, ClientSerializationStreamReader looks like a good start.